# Failed to install PDO

Tags: php, pdo, centos6

I failed install PDO on Centos 6.5 using

```
# pecl install PDO
WARNING: "pecl/PDO" is deprecated in favor of "channel://http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pdo//ext/PDO"
downloading PDO-1.0.3.tar ...

<redacted>

/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo.c: In function ‘php_pdo_get_exception_base’:
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo.c:78: error: too few arguments to function ‘zend_exception_get_default’
make: *** [pdo.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

My PHP version

```
# php -v
PHP 5.4.25 (cli) (built: Mar  7 2014 21:04:52) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Any idea how can I enabled PDO?

Comment: What version of PHP? Have you seen http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php ?

Comment: @deceze PHP 5.4.25. Yes I have read that. Thx.

Comment: PDO *should* be enabled by default. What does `php -i` tell you?

Comment: Only pdo_sqlite and pdo_pgsql installed. Thx @deceze I decide to recompile PHP and now it works. I will keep this question open because I think that is an issue with PHP 5.4.25.